# Unsubscribing from a subscription in dva

Tags: dvajs

I have a model that will subscribe a websocket to several expensive end points when the user is on particular routes. When the user leaves the route, I want to disconnect the websockets.

The [dva api docs](https://github.com/dvajs/dva/blob/master/docs/API.md) say

> Notice: if we want to unregister a model with `app.unmodel()`, it's subscriptions must return unsubscribe method.

However the docs do not include how to register a subscription with an `unsubscribe` method.

How does one create a subscription with an `unsubscribe` handler?

Answer (score 1):

It's necessary to add return to the end of your function.

```
  subscriptions: {
    setup() {
      emitter.on('event', () => {
        emitterCount += 1;
      });

      return () => {
        emitter.removeAllListeners();
      };
    },
  },
```